# IIS sub application not handling requests after upgrading to .NET 6 - returning 307

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, url-rewrite-module, .net-6.0

After installing .NET 6 SDK + hosting bundle, our application stopped handling requests as before.

The IIS setup is the following :

- A root application running on .NET 4.7
- Several sub applications running on .NET core 3.1 (out of process)
- Haproxy in front, sending unencrypted HTTP requests to the IIS (and signing requests).

The root app works fine, but the subapplication stopped handling requests as before.

After enabling the stdout logs on the sub application, I see the requests coming, but it seems the first URL segment is not handled as it should.

Here's the logs :

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://subdomain.domain.net/subapplication/ping  0
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware[2]
      All hosts are allowed.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[4]
      The request path /ping does not match a supported file type
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[1]
      Redirecting to 'https://subdomain.domain.net/subapplication/ping'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[9]
      Connection id "0HMDA5V61D9BR" completed keep alive response.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1.2475ms 307
```

What seems happening is the request miss the controllers middleware, and go to the next one : the StaticFile middleware.

As if after installing .NET 6, the sub application wasn't aware of it's path name `subapplication` in the logs.

I tried uninstalling .NET 6 (+runtime+hosting bundle etc), with no luck.
I also tried to force install .NET 3.1, without luck again.

I'm out of ideas in order to restore the previous correct behavior..

What parameter could have such an impact of the sub app first URL segment handling ? and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround-ed by removing the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` middleware..

But we still don't understand how installing .NET 6 have changed the app behavior on some apps (but not all), and on some IIS servers (but not all).